# How to load columns of hibernate enity dynamically in hibernate during server start

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some columns which has to be loaded based on some configurations,One production Database doesn't have those columns and my other Production box have the column.In this case the same piece of code should work in both the boxes.What is the configuration need to be done to load the columns dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

In general,

for production we should not rely on hibernate to create the ddl . we need to have to have patch so that we can apply that patch into production.

or, we can use database migration tool such as liquibase .

Comment: As an emergency we are unable to do a patch.

Comment: As mentioned, use liquibase to get the delta difference and execute it on require server ...